# Unable to import a module from one directory to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

The above question has been asked multiple times. But with Hard luck I am unable to import modules in one folder into another.

I tried the command in moduele for feature engineering.py file

```
import modulefordatacleaning.Data_Clean_Module as dcm
```

However I get the error modulefordatacleaning doesn't exists..

Is there an easier way rather than adding in the sys.path ?

Please see below the structure of my project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your project file in the same directory, the please use the below

```
from . import modulefordatacleaning.Data_Clean_Module as dcm
```

Comment: Thanks subhro, It however gives me an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" doesn't allow for a . between foldername ( module for data cleaning ) and Module ( Data Clean Module)

Comment: You can once check this official documentation https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references
and make the changes according to the folder structure of your code.